# Squid proxy logging both TCP_DENIED/407 and TCP_TUNNEL/200

Tags: resttemplate, squid

I'm running squid proxy server on ec2, the only squid.conf change I did is below(at the top of squid.conf file)

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
acl squid_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow squid_users
```

I'm now running a spring boot kotlin application on my local and using RestTemplate to call another service running on ec2 server(Let's call it RemoteServer). Below is the code for RestTemplate creation with BasicAuth.

```
var restTemplate = RestTemplate()
    val credentialsProvider = BasicCredentialsProvider()
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
        AuthScope(PROXY_SERVER_HOST, PROXY_SERVER_PORT),
        UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password")
    )
        val proxy = HttpHost(PROXY_SERVER_HOST, PROXY_SERVER_PORT)
        val httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setRoutePlanner(object : DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy){
                override fun determineProxy(target: HttpHost, request: HttpRequest, context: HttpContext): HttpHost {
                    return super.determineProxy(target, request, context)
                }
            })
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).disableCookieManagement()
            .build()
    

    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient))
    val headers = HttpHeaders()



    headers.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;
    headers.accept = Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
val request: HttpEntity<*> = HttpEntity<Any?>(headers)
        val response: ResponseEntity<String> = restTemplate.exchange<String>(
            uri,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            request,
            String::class.java
        )
```

The request is succeeding and I'm getting response on my local server. But I'm seeing two logs in squid's access.log file. First line with TCP_DENIED/407 and second with TCP_TUNNEL/200.

```
1678210437.315      0 <IP> TCP_DENIED/407 4036 CONNECT <api_url>:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1678210460.537  23182 <IP> TCP_TUNNEL/200 6331 CONNECT <api_url>:443 user1 HIER_DIRECT/<IP> -
```

When I invoke the same API of RemoteServer from a browser with auth for squid proxy. I only get a single line in access.log file with TCP_TUNNEL/200.

Unable to understand the addtional TCP_DENIED/407 when using restTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

The first line shows the rejection ([TCP_DENIED/407](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.2)) of the squid to process the request, because the client isn't authenticated yet (the "**-**" after "<api_url>:443").

The second request sends the proper credentials for *user1* to access the squid proxy, and therefore the request succeeds.